# How to implement a decision matrix/table in Clojure

Tags: clojure

There is a requirement to implement a decision table as below:

```
MemberType       Amount      => Discount
"Guest"          > 2000      => 3%
"Silver"         any         => 5%
"Silver"         > 1000      => 10%
"Gold"           any         => 15%
"Gold"           > 500       => 20%
```

I would imagine, if properly implemented in Clojure, we can define a rule table as below:

```
(defrule calc-discount
  [member-type   amount] 
  "Guest"        (greater-than 2000) => 0.03
  "Silver"       (anything)          => 0.05
  "Silver"       (greater-than 1000) => 0.1
  "Gold"         (anything)          => 0.15
  "Gold"         (greater-than 500)  => 0.2
 )
```

Of course, there should be a better way in writing/defining such a rule set. Yet the key thing I think is how to define "defrule" to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this example, you can express the business logic rather concisely with `condp`.

```
(defn discount 
  [member-type amount] 
  (condp (fn [[type tier] _] (and (= member-type type) (> amount tier))) nil 
    ["Guest"  2000] 0.03 
    ["Silver" 1000] 0.10 
    ["Silver"    0] 0.05 
    ["Gold"    500] 0.20
    ["Gold"      0] 0.15 
    0.00))

(discount "Gold" 600) ;=> 0.2
```

If you are looking to implement the syntax as in your example, you'll need to write a macro. A very rough example:

```
(defmacro defrule [name fields & clauses]
  (let [exp (fn [f c] (if (list? c) (list* (first c) f (rest c)) (list `= c f)))]
    `(defn ~name ~fields 
       (cond 
         ~@(for [clause (partition-all (+ 2 (count fields)) clauses)
                 form [(cons `and (map exp fields clause)) (last clause)]] 
             form)))))

(def any (constantly true))

(defrule calc-discount
  [member-type amount]
   "Guest"   (> 2000)  => 0.03
   "Silver"  (> 1000)  => 0.10
   "Silver"     (any)  => 0.05
   "Gold"     (> 500)  => 0.20
   "Gold"       (any)  => 0.15)

(calc-discount "Silver" 1234) ;=> 0.10
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match/)! It's a Clojure library for pattern matching.

Your example would turn out a little something like this....

```
(let [member-type "Gold"
      amount 600]
  (match [member-type amount]
         ["Guest" (_ :guard #(> % 2000))] 0.03
         ["Silver" (_ :guard #(> % 1000))] 0.1
         ["Silver" _] 0.05
         ["Gold" (_ :guard #(> % 500))] 0.2
         ["Gold" _] 0.15
      :else 0))

 ; => 0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you want is a relatable, visual representation in code of various combinations of conditions and their corresponding outcomes, in tabular format.

Check out the `cond-table` macro, which expands your tabular form into a regular `cond` form:
https://github.com/semperos/rankle/blob/master/src/com/semperos/rankle/util.clj

Using this approach, your example could be coded like so:

```clj
(defn discount-for [memtype amount]
  (let [spends? (fn [catgy pred] (and (= memtype catgy)
                                       (pred amount)))
        >n (fn [n] #(> % n))
        any #(< 0 % 501)]
    (util/cond-table 

     :| spends?  (>n 2000) (>n 1000) (>n 500) any 
     :| "Guest"   0.03       0        0       0
     :| "Silver"  0.10       0.10     0.05    0.05
     :| "Gold"    0.20       0.20     0.20    0.15)))

(discount-for "Guest" 3000)
;;=> 0.03
(discount-for "Gold" 25.95)
;;=> 0.15
```